# Javascript add to value if smaller than another value error for more than one digit

Tags: javascript, forms, math

I've got a javascript function that adds one to a quantity if the current value is less than another value. Here is the javascript function:

```
function addQty()
{
    if(document.getElementById("quantity").value < document.getElementById("stock").value)
        document.getElementById("quantity").value++;
    else
        return;
}
```

And here are the form elements that the values are taken from:

```
<input type='text' id="quantity" name='quantity' value ='0' />
<input type='hidden' id="stock" name="stock" value="<?php echo $adjustedStock; ?>" />
```

So basically the user can add one to their quantity of a product to order only if there is enough in stock.

Now, this works absolutely fine if the number in stock is 1-9, but if the stock level is in double digits, the maximum the user can add to their basket (ie the 'quantity' in the code) returns as the first digit + 1. So if the stock is 13 then the max quantity is 2, or if the stock is 63 the max quantity is 7.

I've tried converting the integer value of $adjustedStock to a string before it is used in the form as I read sometimes browsers can behave weirdly in this situation, but this didn't work. Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `1*document.getElementById("quantity").value < 1*document.getElementById("stock").value`

Comment: Thanks Rob - this works nicely! Feel free to enter this as an answer to the question, or I'll put this up in a while if you haven't. Cheers

Comment: if you use type='number' for the input element the javascript engine should handle it correctly, but you are probably better off using parseInt() to be safe. And also should implement some error checking, eg. if the user enters a letter change it to nothing

Comment: Thanks dano - I've got the quantity being controlled by + and - images the user can click and have made the text field readonly to prevent any errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form element values are strings. Use `parseInt` or convert to a number some other way.

Comment: Now that's definitely a useful bit of info - thanks Dave. This does also solve the problem. In terms of a comparison between this solution and Rob's above, would this be a better solution or would either be just as good as the other?

Comment: @CaptainChod It's the same difference; I prefer explicit conversions rather than just doing math on strings--I think it's more communicative. That's just a matter of opinion, though; I'm not sure if it's arguable in a meaningful way. Another option is @amnotiam's unary `+` operator, which IMO is cleaner than a multiplication.

Comment: Yeah I've just put it in both ways to see them next to each other and this way seems a little tidier. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

The "value" attribute of an `<input>` is always a string. Thus your comparison is being done between two strings, which is not what you want.

Convert the values to numbers before comparing:

```
function addQty()
{
    var qtyInp = document.getElementById('quantity'),
      qty = parseInt(qtyInp.value, 10),
      stk = parseInt(document.getElementById('stock').value, 10);

    if (qty < stk)
        qtyInp.value = qty + 1;
}
```

Comment: Great solution. One thing to note: parseFloat is ever so slightly faster, accoring to my tests: http://jsperf.com/str2num

Comment: Thanks Pointy - Dave just beat you to it there! Again, is this a better solution than Rob's (submitted as a comment on the question) or is one just as good as the other?

Comment: @CaptainChod either way is fine; actually that one might be better as `parseInt()`, though "prettier" perhaps, is a dumb API that accepts as numbers strings that *start* with digits and end with garbage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.min()` for this purpose...

```
function addQty() {
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");

    quantity.value = Math.min(+quantity.value + 1, 
                              document.getElementById("stock").value);
}
```

This makes it very clear that you want the lesser of the incremented quantity or the total in stock.